# Avoid repetition in overloaded constructors

Tags: java, overloading

I have one constructor test already, and try to overload this one, code like that:

```
public Test(string a, string b, XXX c, XXX d){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    methodA(a, b, d);
}
public Test(string a, string b, XXX c, XXX d, String e){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    methodA(a, b, d, e);
}
```

the methodA also is an overload method, as you can see "this.a = a; this.b = b;" that part is repeated. How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: Is `methodA(a, b, d)` equivalent to `methodA(a, b, d, null)`?

Comment: Yes, equivalent, just passed one more String

Comment: Then you can have one constructor call the other.  In `Test(a, b, c, d)` call `this(a, b, c, d, null);`.

Comment: Yeah, always best to chain these types of constructors with `this()` calls if possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Thanks for your help :D

Comment: I would go even further and say that, in 99% of cases, you should have one "primary" constructor and all other constructors should do *nothing* but delegate to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `this()` method to avoid the repetition of code.

So what you had was already pretty close to what you needed. Just change the `methodA(...)` call to the `this(...)` call.

I would even go a step further, as suggested in the comments by [@Michael Berry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551406/michael-berry) and [@Silvio Mayolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo), and chain the constructors. The final result should be like this.

```
public Test(string a, string b, XXX c, XXX d, String e){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
}
public Test(string a, string b, XXX c, XXX d){
    this(a, b, c, d, null);
}
```